# Store unique values within foreach loop

Tags: php

Im trying to get value of ids for different values of a foreach loop but im confused how to go about it.

```
$revenue = array('pseudo1', 'pseudo2');

foreach ($revenue as $value) {
    if (!$revenue_type) {
        $st = getValueDescription($value);
        foreach ($st as $stype) {
            $tpe[] = $stype->id;
        }
        $rev[$value] = $tpe;
    }
}
```

when i dump `$rev` this is what i get

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'pseudo1' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '9' (length=1)
          1 => string '19' (length=2)
      'pseudo2' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string '9' (length=1)
          1 => string '19' (length=2)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
          3 => string '35' (length=2)
```

what i actually expect

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'pseudo1' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '9' (length=1)
          1 => string '19' (length=2)
      'pseudo2' => 
        array (size=4)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
          3 => string '35' (length=2)
```

I need the result of my `$rev` to contain `$value` as keys but previous values of `$tpe` keeps adding up with each iteration, im confused how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you provide the input and expected output? The description is pretty unclear

Comment: You are not resetting `$tpe` anywhere, so you are accumulating more elements in that, than you intended. `$tpe = [];` before the inner foreach loop should probably fix your issue. (Right now, it looks like you neglected to initialize that variable completely. Please enable proper PHP error reporting, then PHP can alert you to such mistakes on its own.)

Comment: thank you @CBroe ill do just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
$revenue = array('pseudo1', 'pseudo2');
$uniqueValues = [];

foreach ($revenue as $value) {
    if (!$revenue_type) {
        $st = getValueDescription($value);
        $tpe = [];
        foreach ($st as $stype) {
            if (!in_array($stype->id, $uniqueValues)) {
                $tpe[] = $stype->id;
                $uniqueValues[] = $stype->id;
            }
        }
        $rev[$value] = $tpe;
    }
}
```

$uniqueValues holds the IDS you already added to the $rev variable, and the $tpe gets empty after every iteration